# Java: Multiple representations of the same object

Tags: java, class, object, reference

I have a User.class like this:

```
public class User {
    private HashSet<Client> clients;
    ...
    public void addClient(Client c) {
        c.setParentUser(this);
        clients.add(c);
}
```

And the Client class:

```
public class Client {
    private User parentUser;
    public void setParentUser(User u) {
        parentUser = u;
    }
    ...
}
```

My question is, at the `c.setParentUser(this)`, my intention is to have a "pointer" to the user that holds the client.

So my question is: will `c.setParentUser(this)` just store a reference in the Client, or will it create a new object that is exactly the same as `this` (User)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It stores a reference, like a C/C++ pointer. The variable `parentUser` references the same object as `this` (in the `User` class).

If you want to make a copy, you need to do so explicitly.

Comment: Thanks. I'll accept your answer when n00b-protection allows me to ^.^ (in 12 minutes)

Answer (score 2):

It's a *reference*, not a copy.

Everything other than [primitives](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) (int, double etc.) in Java is a reference. If I write:

```
String s = "abc";
```

then `s` is actually a reference to a `String`, strictly speaking. Not a `String` *per se*. For objects (not primitives) you have to explicitly write a copy constructor to create a copy. If I pass `s` to a method, the reference is copied by value, but it still refers to the original `String` object.

Comment: Note that `String` objects are also a 'bit tricky' as they are unmodifiable. For every string modification a new `String` object is created. So sharing a reference to a `String` does not result in 'both strings' getting updated when you change one... Besides that, nice answer!

Answer (score 0):

Client.parentUser will contain a copy of the reference passed into the `setParentUser` method.

Just be aware that if perform something along the lines of:

```
public void setParentUser(User u) {
    parentUser = u;
    u = new User();
}
```

The reference will have been changed and the reference to the original `User` passed into the function will not be changed if you modify the fields of the `Client.parentUser`.

Answer (score 0):

```
c.setParentUser(this);
```

This is `Has A` Relationship , it just holds the object reffernce of User object.